# Coordinates system used by Get Coordinates on large images

Tags: image

I often try to crop images by selecting a few points manually with the interactive tools and copy-paste them in `ImageTrim[theImage,ThePoints]`.

It works fine on small images and often doesn't work on large images. Here is a example that should be reproductible (Mathematica 12.1, Windows 7).

Let's say I want to crop a little bit this image :

```
TheImage = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Apples"}]
```

I select two points on the diagonal, very near the corners :

[image]

One sees on the animation that the points are at coordinates `{11,15}`, and `{641,425}`. I copy-paste them in ImageTrim :

```
ImageTrim[TheImage, {{11, 15}, {641, 425}}]
```

result :

> [image]

These are only the three apples at the bottom-right of the original image !

**The question**

Where does the coordinates system used by `GetCoordinates` comes from ?

Comment: @LouisB I have also unsuccessfully tried "Get Indices". I will try once again. But first note that the "Get Indices" obtained by the attached cell under the image doesn't give the same values then de "Get Indices" obtained by the contextuel menu. This is probably a bug.

Comment: @LouisB I think you are refering to the"Get Indice" from the attached cell under the image. So far I remember there are also some problems. First I'm surpised that your image is not inverted (Top<-> Bottom inversion). But, as said, I will investigate this further (only tomorrow).

Comment: My deleted comment regarding the indices was wrong.  In MMA 11.3 for Windows I get the expected results using both the Get Coordinates flyout menu selection and the Coordinate Tool dialog shown in your animation.  I then pasted the coordinates from MMA 11.3 into `ImageTrim` in MMA 12.1.0 for Linux and got the same correct result.

But, when I use the coordinates obtained in MMA 12.1.0 for Linux, the results are wrong, as you report.  The coordinates I used were from both the Get Coordinates flyout menu selection and from the Coordinates Tool shown in your animation.

Comment: The coordinate system used by the Get Coordinates tool is in points, not pixels.  The indices are pixel coordinates, top-down.  ImageTrim appears to want them as bottom-up, so a transform would appear to be necessary.

Comment: @ihojnicki I confirm that in this case a transform is necessary on pixel coordinates. I add that this transfom use `ImageDimension[TheImage][[2]]`. It is not convenient for everyday life (!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally understood the origin of the coordinates system used by `GetCoordinates`.

It turns out that the image of apples has a Option called "ImageResolution" :

```
TheImage = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Apples"}];
Options[TheImage]
```

> {ColorSpace -> "RGB", ImageResolution -> {300, 300},   Interleaving ->
> True}

(This option follows the image whatever copy/paste you do with the image. )

On the other hand, the size of the image in pixels is {2700,1800} :

```
ImageDimensions[TheImage]
```

> {2700, 1800}

The coordinate system used by `GetCoordinate` is :

72/300 {2700,1800}

One reconize the 300,2700 and 1800.
Regarding the 72, it is the standard resolution 72 dots/Inch.

Comment: Curiously one can't modify the option ImageResolution of the Image. My workaround is to use Image[ImageData[   theImage  ]].

Comment: The following should work:  `img2 = Image[theImage, ImageResolution -> newValue]`